# How can we specify a method which will be used to authentication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

As far as I understand in the [Spring Security 4.0](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle) framework the method which is going to be used for performing authentication is `POST`. Can I customize it in any way? In my particular task it would be better to use get method for the authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, using GET method to authenticate is not a good method (your parameters are sent clear to the server, it can be bookmarked etc...) so using GET to authenticate is not allowed in Spring security.